# Calculate number of entries / hour

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

I want to calculate the average number of entries done on a Google Sheets.

The sheet is filled by a Google Form so my first column is filled with the date and time the entry is done.

I want to calculate the average number of submissions/hour.

Comment: Could you give us some more specifics on your spreadsheet layout? Maybe give us an image to look at?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
 =count(A2:A)/(24*(max(A:A)-min(A:A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula may work on your Form responses sheet itself:

`=COUNT(A2:A)/((+SORT(A:A,A:A<>"",,ROW(A:A),)-A2)*24)`

It calculates the number of hours that have elapsed between the first submission and the most recent, and then divides this by the number of responses.

If you are placing the formula on another sheet then you would need to prefix the A:A ranges with 'Form responses 1'!